# how to implement simple Sliding Window Algorithm in Matlab or C++

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, sliding-window

i am new one to this site and this is my first query...
i need simple Sliding window algorithm implementation in c++ or matlab
please help me in this regard
 thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: A sliding window is just a general technique with many different applications - it's not a specific algorithm as such. You'll need to be more detailed about your requirements if you want help with this.

Comment: Dear Paul R,
you are right i did not mentioned clearly for what purpose i want this code actually i want code for sliding window for data stream mining.
i you can help me in this regard its very help full
Jonas thanks for you also 
as i mentioned here i have to submit my project for titled "sliding window based data stream mining"

Comment: @zeedotcom: I'm not familiar with data stream mining. Can you explain this with a simple example, please? Ideally, you'd edit your question for that.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you need a generic sliding window for image processing, in Matlab you could do:

```
image = imread('image.png');
imageWidth = size(image, 2);
imageHeight = size(image, 1);

windowWidth = 32;
windowHeight = 32;

for j = 1:imageHeight - windowHeight + 1
    for i = 1:imageWidth - windowWidth + 1
        window = image(j:j + windowHeight - 1, i:i + windowWidth - 1, :);
        % do stuff with subimage
    end
end
```

Comment: Just note that loops in Matlab are slow. You better use some of the "batch" operations as in Jonas' answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the function is a simple linear combination of pixel values in the neighborhood, such as an average, you can use [CONV2](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html) to make the convolution. There are also specialized functions, such as [MEDFILT2](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/medfilt2.html) if you want to take the median of each sliding window.

If the function you want to apply to each neighborhood is more complex, you have two options:

1. If you have enough memory, you can transform your image into a large array such that every column corresponds to one sliding window using [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/im2col.html). Then you apply your function to every column and reshape.
2. If you don't have that much memory, use [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/nlfilter.html) to apply the function to each sliding window.

In any case, you may want to have a look at [PADARRAY](http://www.mathworks.nl/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/padarray.html) to pad your image before you run the convolution to avoid shrinking your image while reducing border effects.

Comment: Good observation re: border effects.

Comment: thanks but my application is about data stream mining

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this for C++, btw the code below was written for OpenCV

```
vector<Rect> get_sliding_windows(Mat& image,int winWidth,int winHeight)
{
  vector<Rect> rects;
  int step = 16;
  for(int i=0;i<image.rows;i+=step)
  {
      if((i+winHeight)>image.rows){break;}
      for(int j=0;j< image.cols;j+=step)    
      {
          if((j+winWidth)>image.cols){break;}
          Rect rect(j,i,winWidth,winHeight);
          rects.push_back(rect);
      }
  } 
  return rects;
}
```